# factoring quadratic with leading coefficient of -1 and both values are the same

Tags: factoring

So I have to factor this quadratic:

$-x^2 + 4$

I've rewritten it as:

$-x^2 + 0x + 4$

Then the factors that add to 0 and multiply to 4 are 2 and -2,
so is the answer $-(x + 2)(x - 2)$ or $-(x - 2)(x + 2)$

Also, another question I have is the answer was written by the professor as:

$(2 - x)(2 + x)$

Which I just don't understand. Is that just another way of writing one of the above factorizations?

Comment: -(ab)=(-a)(b) which in your case is -(x-2)(x+2)=(-(x-2))(x+2)=(2-x)(2+x)

Comment: What if you rewrite the original quadratic as $4-x^2$ and then apply the same factorization rule that you used?

Comment: $(2-x)(2+x)=-(x-2)(x+2)=-(x+2)(x-2)$; $\;-1$ is a *unit*